# Ordered SQL timestamp extraction

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I've tried searching for this subject and got nowhere (can't seem to find the proper key words), so if this is a duplicate, please do tell.

I've been trying to fetch some `time_stamp` from my database and getting them ordered as intervals. For example I run a query such as

```
"SELECT `time_stamp` FROM registo albufeira ".$nome."` WHERE `cota` > '".$piInfo['cota max']."'"
```

and use a php code to arrange intervals of it.

For example if I have the time_stamps that correspond to the following dates:

```
2014-12-30 23:51:00
2014-12-30 23:52:00
2014-12-30 23:53:00
2014-12-30 23:54:00
2014-12-31 01:35:00
2014-12-31 01:36:00
2014-12-31 01:37:00
```

I'd get an intervals array like:

```
[0] => Array
    [0] => 2014-12-30 23:51:00
    [1] => 2014-12-30 23:54:00
[1] => Array
    [0] => 2014-12-31 01:35:00
    [1] => 2014-12-31 01:37:00
```

I have managed to get the php code to get the wanted result, however I feel like this can be achieved using a single SQL query. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: how do you decide what an interval is?

Comment: Forgot to add that, if two following dates and seperated by less than 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(time_stamp) AS `day`, MIN(time_stamp) AS first, MAX(time_stamp) AS last
FROM `registo albufeira`      # fix the table name
WHERE `cota` > '...'          # put your condition here
GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp)
```

It will produce something like:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| day        | first               | last                |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-12-30 | 2014-12-30 23:51:00 | 2014-12-30 23:54:00 |
| 2014-12-31 | 2014-12-31 01:35:00 | 2014-12-31 01:37:00 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

then you can store it in the desired format from the PHP code.

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = array($row['first'], $row['last']);
}
```

The code above will produce the data structure you dumped in the question but I strongly recommend you use string keys ('day', 'first', 'last' whatever you want) instead of numeric ones:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[$row['day']] = $row;
}
```

Add a `print_r($data);` and check the difference.

**Update**:

If the length of an interval is not a day but 300 seconds then replace `DATE(time_stamp)` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 300`.

Comment: Cheers! I've checked this out and the first try gave me good results, just need to tweek it a bit.

I know that string keys are better, and I usually use them, but this time I choose numbered ones.

Comment: No problem. It's your code, you'll fight against it later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Query could be

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%y-%m-%d') AS day_id, 
  MIN(`time_stamp`) AS start_ts,    MAX(`time_stamp`) AS end_ts 
FROM registo
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%y-%m-%d')
```